# php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3425] A remote host refused an attempted connect operation. Crashing server

Tags: php, zend-framework, db2, ibm-midrange, powerpc

Ongoing problem for months, randomly sending 500 errors to the client about once or more a week. Following is the error the client receives until zend is restarted via the 5250 emulator. Our server is an IBMi AS/400 running zendserver 7

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, error 500 Internal Server Error was encountered while attempting to use ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The ONLY errors around the time the server quit responding we receive in the Apache logs is as below. Any other errors (in the PHP logs or zendserver logs) are not near the timestamp of when the server crashes. The error below is showing up repeatedly while the server is in trouble.

```
[Mon Feb 18 14:35:52.082696 2019] [ibm_ssl:error] [pid 230675:tid 00000401] ZSRV_MSG0251: Secure sockets handshake timed out, error = 6011.
[Mon Feb 18 14:35:52.082784 2019] [ibm_ssl:error] [pid 230675:tid 00000401] ZSRV_MSG0281: SSL: 69.213.8.13.
[Mon Feb 18 14:35:52.089664 2019] [ibm_ssl:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003DC] ZSRV_MSG0251: Secure sockets handshake timed out, error = 6011.
[Mon Feb 18 14:35:52.089680 2019] [ibm_ssl:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003DC] ZSRV_MSG0281: SSL: 69.213.8.13. 

...

[Mon Feb 18 14:38:20.769832 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003F3] Can not connect() to /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3425] A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:20.887512 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003DE] Can not read response from /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3447] A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:24.841288 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003F5] Can not read response from /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3447] A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:25.964048 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003E1] Can not read response from /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3447] A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:25.964528 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003E1] Can not connect() to /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3425] A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:25.966320 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003E1] Can not connect() to /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3425] A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.
[Mon Feb 18 14:38:25.966600 2019] [zend_enabler:error] [pid 230675:tid 000003E1] Can not connect() to /usr/local/zendphp7/bin/php-cgi.bin (0.0) - [3425] A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.
```

The following is the status of the zend related jobs while the server is sending 500 errors

```
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCH      .0  PGM-QZHBMAIN     SIGW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-QZSRLOG      SIGW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-QZSRLOG      SIGW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-QZSRHTTP     SIGW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-zfcgi        SELW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   THDW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   THDW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   SELW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   SELW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZENDPHP7     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-php-cgi.bi   TIMW
        ZSDEPLMNG    QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-watchdog     THDW 
        ZSDEPLMNG    QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-zdd          RUN  
        ZSJAVA_BRG   QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-watchdog     THDW 
        ZSJAVA_BRG   QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-jFromPASE    EVTW 
        ZSJAVA_BRG   QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  JVM-com.zend.j   SELW 
        ZSMONMNG     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-watchdog     THDW 
        ZSMONMNG     QTMHHTTP    BCI      .0  PGM-MonitorNod   SELW
```

No idea where to go from here, google has not been helpful.

Comment: This question is not about programming, but maybe about configuration. So stackoverflow may be the wrong place. Troubleshooting required. An SSL trace may help. The SSL handshake timeout suggests that the client (i.e. that making the connection attempt) is not responding in time. You need to know the SSL configuration details, the mod_ibm_ssl version, what SSL Timeouts are configured (or defaulted) and whether increasing them can help, and whether the client environment is resource-stressed at the time. Seek to recreate on a non-prod environment. Engage suitably experienced troubleshooters.

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest cume, as well as the latest group PTFs, especially HTTP. Do other SSL applications work, or is it only PHP that is falling over?

Comment: @mao Where might I find some people willing to help? We have another application that runs the same settings and versions, but it's an older version of our PHP application, that hasn't crashed since I've been here. I thought it might have to do with a bad loop in PHP or something, but we've not been able to find it.

Comment: @BuckCalabro I will check this out ASAP and get back. Other SSL applications work to my knowledge. SSH works consistently as well.

Comment: The web mailing list at midrange dot com has people familiar with PHP running on IBM i.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @DylanMcGreevy Not yet, we have created a node app that pings the website and calls an RPG program to restart Apache, and this brings it back up in a reasonable amount of time (less than 1 minute compared to the 5+ minutes before) as a band-aid. We think it is related to a lot of requests in a short amount of time. Which, hosting an AJAX heavy site, is unavoidable.